# ./node_modules/react-router-dom/react-router-dom.js Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

`./node_modules/react-router-dom/react-router-dom.js Attempted import error: 'Navigate' is not exported from 'react-router'.`

The version of react-router-dom is 6.0.0-alpha.2 and react-router is 5.2.0.
Both are installed correctly. I'm not sure how to fix this error. Can someone please give me any possible solution?

There's not even a single `<Navigate to=?>` line in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you installed both only one of them is required, this will work

1. Do npm remove react-router
2. Delete the node_modules
3. yarn install or npm install and
4. yarn start or npm start

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I only need of one them. But, I got a new error saying `Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.` even though react-router-dom is installed correctly.

Comment: you need to import it as {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"